# Latest news about Eclipse 4.0

Tags: eclipse

What are the "latest" news about the next big release of the Eclipse IDE? (3.5 Galileo could also be of interest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Eclipse2009](http://www.eclipsecon.org/2009/) gave us some hints about the next upcoming relase of the Eclipse IDE.

After a quick googling it seems like there will be some new cool "cloud" feature/support. (suprise! :) ) 
Except that, Eclipse 4.0 will provide a uniform, pervasive platform across computing environments (Web / RIA, Desktop, Server, Cloud, Embedded)

[Some new features that will be included in Eclipse 3.5 Galileo](http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/S-3.5M6-200903130100/eclipse-news-M6.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's planned to be a release the summer of 2010, but there will be an Eclipse 3.6 release and perhaps even a 3.7 etc. so it's to separate tracks.

On EclipseCon 2009 there was a lot of talk about how the user interface is going to modelled (using EMF), but there will be compatibility layer so you will be able to run your old plugins in e4 without large rewrites, if any.

They also talked about the Eclipse Runtime, which is way to use Eclipse functionality in other ways than just in the IDE, e.g in middle-ware.

Answer (score 1):

We're in the process of building a proper site for the upcoming Galileo release. It *should be* something like http://www.eclipse.org/galileo when it's ready (hopefully sometime this week).

In the meantime, you can get a sense for what will be included in the Galileo release from the [Galileo wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Galileo). It's intended more for the developers of the various projects than for adopters. It does give a list of the projects involved; from there you can get a sense for the sort of functionality you can expect.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Its planned to be relased 2010

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of E4 topics covered in EclipseCon a couple weeks ago.
The conference website is here: http://www.eclipsecon.org/2009/

You can see the list of talks, and see the slides with the "view in gPublication"

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good place to start. There's a newsgroup and mailing list.

[Project Summary - eclipse.e4](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=eclipse.e4)